# Haskell: how to get rid of the memory leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

I was trying "all possible" tricks I came across the internet, with "all possible" combinations of `!`, `seq`, `deepseq`, ... but I could not find the way to suppress the leaking of memory in the following program

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.List
import Control.DeepSeq

foldl'' f z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `deepseq` foldl'' f z' xs 
foldl'' _ z [] = z

statistics :: [[Double]] -> [(Double, Double)]
statistics (z:zs) = normalize $ foldl'' go acc zs
  where acc = map (\x -> (x, x^2)) z
        go = zipWith (\(a, b) x -> (a + x, b + x^2))
        n  = 1 + (length zs)  
        dn = fromIntegral n
        normalize = map (\(a, b) -> (a / dn, (b - a^2 / dn) / dn))

main =  mapM_ (putStrLn . show) (statistics ps)
   where ps = take nn $ unfoldr (Just . splitAt mm) $ map sin [1..]
         nn = 1000
         mm = 1000
```

which calculates the mean and the variance of "`mm` variables from `nn` measurements".

Can you give me a hint?

**EDIT**

As pointed out in answers, the problem is in calling `length`. So the better version could be

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.List
import Control.DeepSeq

foldl'' f z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `deepseq` foldl'' f z' xs 
foldl'' _ z [] = z

statistics :: [[Double]] -> [(Double, Double)]
statistics (z:zs) = normalize $ foldl'' go acc zs
   where acc = (1, map (\x -> (x, x^2)) z)
         go = \(n, abs) xs -> (n + 1, zipWith (\(a, b) x -> (a + x, b + x^2)) abs xs)
         normalize (n, abs) = map (\(a, b) -> (a / n, (b - a^2 / n) / n)) abs

main =  mapM_ (putStrLn . show) (statistics ps)
   where ps = take nn $ unfoldr (Just . splitAt mm) $ map sin [1..]
         nn = 100
         mm = 1000000
```

but it still leaks if `mm` is large because of a thunk created by `zipWith`. Instead I have tried

```
zipWith' f xs ys = go f [] xs ys
   where go f zs (a:as) (b:bs) = 
             let zs' = (f a b) : zs in go f zs' as bs
         go _ zs _ _ = foldl' (\x y -> y : x) [] zs
```

but unsuccessfully.

**EDIT**

The profiling output for the second improved example and for `nn=100` and `mm=1e6`:

```
   leak +RTS -p -h -RTS

total time  =        5.18 secs   (5180 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 4,769,555,408 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

    COST CENTRE       MODULE  %time %alloc

    main              Main     67.4   64.0
    main.ps           Main     18.1   21.6
    statistics.go.\   Main      6.7   11.7
    statistics.go.\.\ Main      5.3    1.9
    foldl''           Main      1.5    0.0


                                               individual     inherited
 COST CENTRE                 no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

 MAIN                         46           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main                        94           0   67.4   64.0    67.4   64.0
  CAF                         91           0    0.0    0.0    32.6   36.0
   main                       92           1    0.0    0.0    32.6   36.0
    main.mm                   97           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.nn                   96           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.ps                   95           1   18.1   21.6    18.1   21.6
    statistics                93           1    0.0    0.0    14.5   14.4
     statistics.normalize    106           1    0.4    0.4     0.8    0.5
      statistics.normalize.\ 107      100000    0.4    0.1     0.4    0.1
     statistics.acc          102           1    0.2    0.3     0.3    0.3
      statistics.acc.\       104      100000    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
     statistics.go           100           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     foldl''                  98          30    1.5    0.0    13.5   13.6
      foldl''.z'              99          29    0.0    0.0    12.0   13.6
       statistics.go         101           0    0.0    0.0    12.0   13.6
        statistics.go.\      103          29    6.7   11.7    12.0   13.6
         statistics.go.\.\   105     2900000    5.3    1.9     5.3    1.9
```

[image]

It seems, like Thomas M. DuBuisson suggested, that the "leak" is related to the construction of `ps`, but how else could it be constructed?

Comment: First, post code that compiles (I see your `where` clause is not aligned and uses variable names that start with a capital letter).  Second, post specifics of the problem (why do you think this is a memory leak?  Do you see that you are forcing the entire list into memory due to the `length` call?).

Comment: How do you know this new 'leak' is the fault of `zipWith` and not, say, `foldr (Just . splitAt mm)`?

Comment: I don’t think your edited code has a speak leak in the strict sense: Your accumulator in in `foldl''` contains a list of 1000000 elements that you force using deepseq; that naturally causes a lot of memory consumption.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner But not 24G for nn = 1e2 and mm = 1e6?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner typo: 24G => 240M

Comment: A list of 1000000 doubles on a 64 bit machine should take 1000000×(3+2)×8 bytes, roughly 40MB. so yes, then there is still a leak somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I completely lack intuition about these things, but I really can not see why `foldr (Just . splitAt mm) xs` would leak, even less so if I replace it with something like `samples mm xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt mm xs in as : samples mm bs`. I dont see  what would, like you would sey, force `ps` into memory?

Comment: Minor style comment: No need to use a lambda in the definition of `go`, you can just put the arguments on the left of the `=`

Comment: If I run this code, the memory bar stays constant most of the time, but also 240MB. This number does not change when I vary `nn` from 2 upwards. Also, the calculation of the state size is wrong: The list contains 1000000 tuples of Doubles, so 1000000 * (3 + 3 + 2 + 2) * 8 = 80MB, and we get (a bit) closer to 240MB. If there is another such list somewhere and we add a bit overhead for the generational GC, we might have the observed 240MB. Did you try profiling?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Can you just explain (3 + 2) factor pleas?

Comment: 3 words for the `:` constructor, 3 words for the `(,)` constructor, 2 words for the left `Double`, 2 words for the right `Double`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly a guess, but your call to `length xs` to obtain `n` forces the spine of the input list `xs`, creating lots of thunks. For a quick test, use `1000` instead of `dn` and see if it helps.

For full laziness, you could try to define normalize without having to pre-calculate the length of the list. But that is probably quite tricky to achieve...

In your edited code I believe is no real space leak, just expensive data structures. The code runs much faster and in 133MB of ram after switching to unboxed vectors. Note how I had to change nothing but to add a few `V.` to functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.List
import Control.DeepSeq
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

foldl'' f z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `deepseq` foldl'' f z' xs 
foldl'' _ z [] = z

statistics :: [V.Vector Double] -> V.Vector (Double, Double)
statistics (z:zs) = normalize $ foldl'' go acc zs
   where acc = (1, V.map (\x -> (x, x^2)) z)
         go = \(n, abs) xs -> (n + 1, V.zipWith (\(a, b) x -> (a + x, b + x^2)) abs xs)
         normalize (n, abs) = V.map (\(a, b) -> (a / n, (b - a^2 / n) / n)) abs

main =  V.mapM_ (putStrLn . show) (statistics ps)
   where ps = take nn $ map V.fromList $ unfoldr (Just . splitAt mm) $ map sin [1..]
         nn = 100
         mm = 1000000
```

Running this with `+RTS -s` gives these statistics (I pressed Ctrl-C while the output is running, hence the short execution time):

```
   3,009,534,792 bytes allocated in the heap
     324,022,224 bytes copied during GC
      51,390,128 bytes maximum residency (16 sample(s))
       4,896,504 bytes maximum slop
             133 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      5617 colls,     0 par    0.20s    0.20s     0.0000s    0.0006s
  Gen  1        16 colls,     0 par    0.10s    0.10s     0.0063s    0.0322s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.39s  (  5.59s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.30s  (  0.30s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.70s  (  5.89s elapsed)

  %GC     time      17.8%  (5.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,163,064,609 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  82.2% of total user, 23.7% of total elapsed
```

The maximum residency is roughly 50MB, which corresponds well to three copies of a 1000000 unboxed vectors of pairs of doubles being live at the same time during `V.zipWith`. The difference between the 50MB of data on the heap and the 133MB of memory in use comes from the fact that we have a copying garbage collector (which double the demand) and probably some overhead from the run time system or other components.

Comment: But assuming that there is at least a factor of 2 improvement using unboxed vectors over lists, there is still a mysterious 133MB?